# Angular: Can I pass values from the console to a component like how a parent component passes a value to its child?

Tags: angular

For example, a parent component can pass in a value to its child component like below in its html file:

```
[name]='Ben'
```

As I'm trying to do several tests with a whole bunch of properties, is there a way to do it more efficiently besides doing it via query parameters?
Could I do it via the console instead by placing an observable and maybe there's a function I can call in the console that takes in json format.
So for example i can call this in the console:

```
dothis("listOfThings":[{"name":'Ben', "age":'30'}])
```

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

One way to go after this could be:

1. Create an array that contains your "bunch of properties" in the component class
2. Create a button in the template
3. Add event listener to button
4. On click, the button triggers a method in the component class that does what you need

By the way, your first example is data binding:

```
[name]='Ben'
```

If you don't use @Input you won't pass anything from parent to child. Here is an [example](https://www.vitainbeta.org/2021/08/05/how-to-pass-data-property-to-child-components-in-angular/). Maybe you are familiar with this. Forgive me if this is redundant.